# UPDATE or INSERT in SQL Server with specific requirements

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I need to insert records into a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExamFees]
(
    [ExamSeriesID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Region] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Fee] [money] NOT NULL,
    [DatetimeEntered] [datetime] NULL
)
```

However, if a record already exists then I only want to set DatetimeEntered to GETDATE().

I think I need to use merge, but I'm not sure how to do this and have been told that I can lose data if I don't know what I'm doing.

Some example data is:

```
INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(553, 'Low', 10.00, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(553, 'Lower mid', 20.00, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(553, 'Upper mid', 30.00, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(553, 'High', 40.00, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(401, 'Low', 5.00, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(401, 'Lower mid', 10.00, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(401, 'Upper mid', 15.00, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(401, 'High', 20.00, GETDATE())
```

It is worth mentioning that this will will be called from a C# program too.

The SQL is generated en mass and added to a StringBuilder, like so:

```
string Region = "Low";

string ExamFeesTableName = "ExamFees";

sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO " + ExamFeesTableName + "([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES(" + ExamSeriesID + ", '" + Region + "', " + Fee.ToString("0.00") + ", GETDATE())");
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I suspect your question was downvoted for not showing any research effort.  Of course without a comment we'll never know...  The docs for MERGE can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx).

Comment: you could always do a check first with if exists(select count(1) from ExamFees where blablabla) then update else insert. Not the most elegant solution but works and is still easy to read and maintain

Comment: I apologise for it appearing as if I haven't researched this. I have been trying to perform a merge as it seems on the surface like the most efficient way to do it, but I didn't understand it and didn't want to risk getting it wrong.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins For a MERGE statement, you'll need something in the USING clause. For example: MERGE INTO ExamFees a USING someTable b ON (a.ExamSeriesID = b.ExamSeriesID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET DatetimeEntered = GETDATE() WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES('553', 'Low', 10.00, GETDATE();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest picking a strategy similar to one of the following approaches:

**Method 1**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ExamFees WHERE ExamSeriesID='553' and Region = 'Low')
    UPDATE ExamFees SET DatetimeEntered = GETDATE() WHERE ExamSeriesID='553' and Region = 'Low'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES('553', 'Low', 10.00, GETDATE())
```

**Method 2**

```
UPDATE ExamFees SET DatetimeEntered = GETDATE() WHERE ExamSeriesID='553' and Region = 'Low'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
        INSERT INTO ExamFees([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) VALUES('553', 'Low', 10.00, GETDATE())
```

These examples are based on your first `INSERT` statement, and will need to be repeated for each of the INSERT statements.

Comment: I was hoping to learn how to do a merge, but this works well for me. I have made an InsertOrUpdate(..) C# method based on this that I can replace later if I figure out how to do the same thing via a MERGE. Thank you, Jacob. If I figure out how to do merge properly and it works then I will add it as a third method to your answer.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins
For a MERGE statement, you'll need something in the USING clause. For example:

MERGE INTO ExamFees a
  USING someTable b
    ON (a.ExamSeriesID = b.ExamSeriesID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET DatetimeEntered = GETDATE()
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([ExamSeriesID], [Region], [Fee], [DatetimeEntered]) 
    VALUES('553', 'Low', 10.00, GETDATE();